# Web IRC - how do I filter out the noise of people leaving and entering a room?

Tags: irc

I log in to http://webchat.freenode.net/ regularly. But in most channels, the amount of chatting is lesser than the notifications of users entering/leaving. Is there a command I can use that either hides this data or gives it a different color so I can ignore it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Menu** (top left corner) > **Options** > **Hide Joins/Parts/Quits**. You can also try some [desktop IRC client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_clients).